# Setup model for company-users-relations model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a bit struggling with the setup of my models. I have companies which have many users and have many relations. When I show relations in a view, it should only show the relations belonging to the company (otherwise users from other companies would also see them!). My current model setup is:

company has_many users
users belong_to company

company has_many relations
relations belong_to company

users has_many relations
relations belong_to user

I was thinking that when a user is logged in, you should be able to request for something like "current_user.relations", and because of the model relations it would only show the relations of the company of the current logged in user. Is this true and how can I implement this?

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relations
end
```

Then in controller:

```
current_user.company.relations
```

would return relations of users company.

Comment: Thanks. But when I then ask for the contacts of a relation, I would assume it would be "current_user.company.relations.contacts.find :all", but that returns a "Could not find the association :relation in model Company" error. (company has_many :contacts, :through => :relation and contact belongs_to relation)

Comment: Use `current_user.company.contacts` as you defined `contacts` on `Company`, but instead of `has_many :contacts, :through => :relation` use `has_many :contacts, :through => :relations`